# Discrete time system MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, discrete-mathematics

How could I initialize x at time 2013? I need x0= 0.9914 as initial conditions
Here my example:

```
A=[1]
B=[0.12]
C=[1]
D=[0]

u=[12.9 13 13.01 13.02 13.019 13.03 13.03]

sistema=ss(A,B,C,D,-1)
t=[2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019];    
y=lsim(sistema,u,t);
plot(t,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you forgot to create the initial conditions variable.

```
x0 = 0.9914;
```

Then all you need to do is add it to the `lsim` function.

```
y=lsim(sistema, u, t, x0);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please provide an explanation why and how your answer solves the problem.